# PHP working in PHPStorm but not on ngnix server

Tags: php, nginx

so I have a website and I am trying to add the current RPI to this website in a text box on the initialisation of the website.

```
<?php
$html = 
file_get_contents('https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices'); 
//get the html returned from the following url
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$classname="stand-out";
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

global $RPI;
$temp = substr($nodes[0]->nodeValue , 0 , 4);
$RPI = floatval($temp);
?>
```

So this is my code for getting the RPI and below is my code for adding it into the HTML

```
<input id="rpi" type="text" class="form-control txbx" value="<?php echo $RPI ?>" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
```

I have PHP in other parts of my code and the versions of PHP on my my machine and on the nginx web server are both the same. So when I add this into my code and run it in PHPStorm it works fine but when on the website it does not work as shown.

The PHP code is in another file and I did try move it to a different file that had php that did provide php variables that did work on the website however this did not fix anything.

[image: looks like this in webserver]
[image: looks like this in PHPStorm]
No errors are shown in any form

I hope I have provided enough detail here but if not then please say

Comment: Please be more specific. What does _break the website_ mean? What is the actual problem? Do you see any error messages? Does anything get logged to the error log?

Comment: I have added in some more information hope this helps?

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log? This question is impossible to answer in its current form. There is no obvious reason that the numbers should be missing without further context. To get a answer you need to identify the problem.

Comment: Do some debugging.  Does your `file_get_contents()` call actually get anything?  If not, maybe [`fopen_wrappers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) are not enabled?  What is your global `$RPI`? Might it be different on the live server?

Comment: Hi thanks for the help turns out php7.0-xml wasnt installed so just had to do sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml , thanks again